# Proof for primitive pythagorean triples

Tags: geometry

I was wondering if there was a proof that any integer pythagorean triple can be represented as a positive integer multiple of a primitive pythagorean triple. This seems quite related to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, so I was wondering if the proof would be similar.

Comment: How are you defining a primitive pythagorean triple?

Comment: This looks like a circular argument: either the numbers in the triple are not coprimes and you can simplify, or they are coprimes and you call them primitive.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you have a pythgorean triple $(a,b,c)$ divide each number by $gcd(a,b,c)$ and remember if $p$ divides any two of the new numbers it must divide the third.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial from the definition.

We say that $(a,b,c)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple if it is a Pythagorean Triple and there do not exist $(a',b',c')$, also a Pythagorean Triple, such that $\exists k$ such that $a=ka'$ etc.

Let $(a,b,c)$ be a Pythagorean triple. If it's primative, $k=1$ and we are done. If it's not, the. $\exists k$ such that...

Answer (score 0):

It is known all the pythagorean triples are given by $$(\lambda(s^3-t^2), \lambda(2st),\lambda(s^2+t^2))$$ where $(s,t)=1$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb N$. The answer to your question it clearly follows.